# Why doesn't this simple physics freefall code work

Tags: c#

I have some code I created to simulate a freefall of an object in a vacuum. When timestep is set to 1000ms it works perfectly with no problems. when I set timestep lower than 1000ms it deviates wildly from actual values falling far faster than normal. It takes around 14 seconds to fall 1000 meters at 1000ms which is the correct value.    At 100ms timestep it only takes 5 seconds.  at 10ms it only takes 2.2 seconds.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  I thought I set the timestep calculation to be able to handle smaller steps.

Thank you

```
        Body testbody = new Body();
        testbody.pos = new Vector(0, 1000);
        testbody.velocity = new Vector(0, 0);
        Bodytrack(testbody);

        static void Bodytrack(Body body)
        {
            watch.Start();
            int timestep = 1000;
            while (body.pos.Y > 0)
            {
                body.pos = body.pos + (body.velocity * (timestep / 1000.0));
                if (body.pos.Y <= 0) { break; }
                Thread.Sleep(timestep);
                CalculateAcceleration(body);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(body.velocity.Y);
                Console.WriteLine(body.pos.Y);
                Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            }
            watch.Stop();
        }



        public static void CalculateAcceleration(Body body)
        {
            body.acceleration = new Vector(0, -9.80665);
            body.velocity = Vector.Add(body.acceleration, body.velocity); 
        }
```

Comment: At no point you are using `timestep` to calculate the new velocity....

Comment: body.acceleration is in meters per second per second but you don't use the time step to affect it

Comment: And additionally to the comments above: when you implement it correctly having smaller steps will make it fall faster and it's expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
body.acceleration = new Vector(0, -9.80665);
```

Every time through the loop, you set the acceleration to -9.8 (which is the acceleration for 1000ms) instead of the acceleration for the amount of time that has passed.

You need to take into account the amount of time that as passed.  If 500ms has passed, then acceleration should only be -9.80665/2.

You need to change the method to this:

```
public static void CalculateAcceleration(Body body, int timestep)
{
   body.acceleration = new Vector(0, -9.80665 * (timestep/1000));
   body.velocity = Vector.Add(body.acceleration, body.velocity); 
}
```

Comment: I see, should I also keep the timestep/1000 in the part that sets body.pos? Or should  I delete it from there?

Comment: Does `timestep/1000` need to be `timestep/1000.0` to prevent integer division?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge yes it does (But if the parentheses where gone it would not because the `-9.80665 * timestep` would have happened first and made it a double)

Comment: Huh...? Acceleration is constant in this case (and should remain so): it refers to gravitational acceleration on Earth. This code works, but it is wrong (that's kind of shocking, actually). This adjusts the body's velocity to the new instant after each `timestep`, but altering the body's acceleration is wrong. Just assign the first vector to a temporary variable and use it to recalculate velocity. While on that, rename the method to something like `UpdateVelocity` or similar. Not my intention to be rude, disrespectful, pedant, nor anything the like... just thought this should be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember my math correctly (and manage to write it down using markdown)...

The idea is that the horizontal position is not affected by anything, gravity only affects the vertical position. So we can easily calculate where the object is horizontally (assuming no collisions).

`X(t) = Vx * t`.

This means that when you throw something horizontally at 10 metres per second, it will have traveled 100 metres after 10 seconds.

The formula för the horizontal positioning is a bit more advanced. It contains two parts, the first part is the movement without gravity, and the second part acts as a countering force by the gravity.

`Y(t) = Vy * t - (g * t^2)/2` where g is gravity (usually 9.82).

`Vy * t` is the constant motion upwards if gravity wouldn't have pulled it down.
`(g * t^2)/2` is the increasing pull of gravity.

A object that's dropped will have no initial force in any direction, thus { `Vx = 0`, `Vy = 0` } and you can easily get the current position of it, at any time, using `pos(t) = -(g * t^2)/2`. (We also know that it will fall straight down so you do not have to calculate any horizontal positioning.) You already know the speed of it by `speed(t) = g * t`.

You can not trust time-slices as your code does. For one, Thread.Sleep isn't exact. It's better if you calculate time elapsed since last update, and use that in your calculations.

Comment: The formula is the same for horizontal and vertical it is `P(t) = P0 + V0 * t + (a * t^2)/2` where `a = -g` for the vertical and `a = 0` for the horizontal.

Comment: I considered this but If the object changes direction or i implement drag that method would no longer work.